# How can I slow down the refresh rate in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to python and I'm trying to make a simple platformer game using pygame. My issue is that when I use a `while` loop to make a block fall until it hits the bottom of the screen, it travels there all at once and I can't see it happening. However when I move the block side to side using `if` statements, I can see that happening. How can I slow down the falling block down so it's visible?

I was following a tutorial for the most part, but wanted to add my own thing.

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and x > 0:
        x = x - 5
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and x < (500 - width):
        x = x + 5
    if keys[pygame.K_s]: #this is the portion that is too fast. 
        while y < (500 - height):
            y = y + 5    
    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (player_color), (x,y,width,height))
    pygame.display.update()
```

I tried putting the entire `while ... y = y + 5` code into an `if` as well; that slowed it down, but it only moved when I held down the `s` key.

Comment: Have you tried changing the fps variable?

Comment: You can also slow it down by making the object move slower, basically by changing the amount it moves per loop.

Comment: Just noticed you change the `y` in the while loop without updating the display/screen and the player

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want it to fully 'animate' down, you should add the code that keeps the pygame screen/player updating in your while loop, otherwise you're just changing the `y` without changing the screen. So your code would look somewhat like this:

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and x > 0:
        x = x - 5
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and x < (500 - width):
        x = x + 5
    if keys[pygame.K_s]: #this is the portion that is too fast. 
        while y < (500 - height):
            y = y + 5 
            player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (player_color), (x,y,width,height)) # Make sure to update the player
            pygame.display.update() # Make sure to update the display
    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (player_color), (x,y,width,height))
    pygame.display.update()
```

**Changing the FPS:**
But, if you do want to change the speed of the game loop/essentially the frames per second, you can simply change the `fps` variable/the `clock.tick()` argument. So for example:

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 30 # This value is the amount of frames per second
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps) # The argument (currently fps) passed into this method will change the frames per second
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and x > 0:
        x = x - 5
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and x < (500 - width):
        x = x + 5
    if keys[pygame.K_s]: #this is the portion that is too fast. 
        while y < (500 - height):
            y = y + 5    
    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (player_color), (x,y,width,height))
    pygame.display.update()
```

You can read more about the `clock.tick()` method [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick)

*Please mark my answer as accepted if it solved your issue*